# Passport.js: Redirect to last page after log in/out

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, passport.js

I want to be able to redirect the user back to their last visited page before they logged in. This is my code so far:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/',
  failureFlash: true
}));
```

Instead of `'/'` on both `successRedirect` and `failureRedirec`t I want to have something like req.body.url. In this scenario I'd post with `AJAX` and I'd have this in its body: `data: {url: window.location.pathname}`. But passport I don't know how to implement another callback function in the post body above (again, for both `successRedirect` and `failureRedirect` with `failureFlash` included. Can you help me please? Thank you!